# Retrieve hashed password in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi everyone I have a question, I have stored password in database using hash method of codeigniter. The format of password is this

```
hash('sha256', $password -> password . 'az2x@_.@!`~$aezxqy+=@%^&');
```

Now i want to get the original password back. How can i do that?

Comment: I think you want to get the hash, the original password was in plain text and after to apply sha256 you can't get it in plain.

Check this: https://gist.github.com/Taytus/1628134

Answer (score 0):

Once any string is saved as hashed string then it cannot be retrieved back. You can add a seperate column in database where you can store the real password. When user update his password, you can update the other column as well with the real password string.

Comment: Thumbs up for the answer.